# TENGO UN PROBLEMA MUY RARO Undefined variable: users (View: C:\Nueva carpeta\sisbegn\resources\views\users\index.blade.php)

Tags: php, laravel-6

ESTOY MUY CONFUNDIDO ESTO ME APARECE Undefined variable: users (View: C:\Nuevacarpeta\sisbegn\resources\views\users\index.blade.php) ese es el archivo index.blade.php de la vista de los USUARIOS de mi sistema pero yo NO estoy trabajando sobre ese modulo si no sobre mi módulo de MATERIAS-PARALELOS
El error me sale cuando hago clic en el menu

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi ruta de usuarios es esta

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

y la ruta en la que estoy trabajando es esta

```
Route::resource('levels_subjects', 'LevelSubjectController');
```

esto tengo en el controlador de mis Usuarios

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\User;
use App\Models\Rol;
use App\Http\Requests\UserFormRequest;
use Flash;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {

}

public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request) {
        $searchText = trim((string)$request->get('searchText'));
        $users = DB::table('users as u')
        ->join('roles as r', 'u.rol_id', '=', 'r.rol_id')
        ->select('u.id', 'u.name', 'u.lastName', 'u.idCard', 'u.email', 'u.password', 'r.rol_name')
        ->where('u.name','LIKE','%'.$searchText.'%')
        ->orwhere('u.lastName','LIKE','%'.$searchText.'%')
        ->orwhere('u.idCard','LIKE','%'.$searchText.'%')
        ->orderBy('u.lastName','asc')
        ->paginate(7);

        return view('users.index', compact('users','searchText'));
    } 
}

public function create() {

    $roles = DB::table('roles')->where('rol_id', '>', '0')->get();
    return view("users.create", compact('roles'));
}

public function store(UserFormRequest $request) {
    $user = new User;
    $user -> rol_id = $request->get('rol_id');
    $user -> name = $request->get('name');
    $user -> lastName = $request->get('lastName');
    $user -> idCard = $request->get('idCard');
    $user -> email = $request->get('email');
    $user -> password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    $user -> save();
    return redirect(route('users.index'));
}

public function show($id) {
    return view('users.show',['user'=>User::findOrFail($id)]);
}

public function edit($id) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $roles = DB::table('roles')->where('rol_id', '>', '0')->get();
    return view('users.edit',["user"=>$user, "roles"=>$roles]);

}

public function update(UserFormRequest $request, $id) {
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);
    $user -> rol_id = $request->get('rol_id');
    $user -> name = $request->get('name');
    $user -> lastName = $request->get('lastName');
    $user -> idCard = $request->get('idCard');
    $user -> email = $request->get('email');
    $user -> password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
    $user -> update();
    return redirect(route('users.index'));
}

public function destroy($id) {

    $user = User::where('id', $id)->delete();
    Flash::success('Eliminado exitosamente.');
    return redirect(route('users.index'));
}

}
```

esto tengo en mi modelo del Usuario

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

protected $table = 'users';
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'rol_id',
    'name',
    'lastName',
    'idCard', 
    'email', 
    'password',
    // 'photo',
];
}
```

Esta tengo en mi archivo index.blade.php

```html
                        <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="roles-table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>N°</th>
                                <th>Nombres y Apellidos</th>
                                <th>Cédula</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Rol</th>
                                
                                <th colspan="3">Acciones</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @foreach($users as $us)
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{!! $us->id !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $us->lastName !!} {!! $us->name !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $us->idCard !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $us->email !!}</td>
                                    <td>{!! $us->rol_name !!}</td>
                                
                                    <td>
                                    {!! Form::open(['route' => ['users.destroy', $us->id], 'method' => 'delete']) !!}
                                        <div class='btn-group'>
                                            <a href="{!! route('users.show', [$us->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-warning'>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open">Ver</i>
                                            </a>
                                            <a href="{!! route('users.edit', [$us->id]) !!}" class='btn btn-info'>
                                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit">Editar</i>
                                            </a>
                                            
                                            {!! Form::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash">Eliminar</i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'onclick' => "return confirm('Confirma que desea Eliminar?')"]) !!}
                                        </div>
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                        </tbody>
                                
                            @endforeach
                    </table>
```

Por si acaso esto tengo en mi controlador de Materias-Paralelos

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Models\Level;
use App\Models\Subject;
use App\Models\Period;
use App\Models\LevelSubject;

use App\Http\Requests\LevelSubjectFormRequest;
use Flash;

class LevelSubjectController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {

}

public function index(Request $request) {
    if ($request) {
        $searchText = trim((string)$request->get('searchText'));
        $levels_subjects = DB::table('levels_subjects as ls')
        ->join('levels as l', 'ls.lev_id', '=', 'l.lev_id')
        ->join('subjects as s', 'ls.sub_id', '=', 's.sub_id')
        ->join('periods as p', 'ls.per_id', '=', 'p.per_id')
        ->select('ls.lev_sub_id', 'l.lev_name', 's.sub_name', 'p.per_name') //'u.photo'
        ->where('s.sub_name','LIKE','%'.$searchText.'%')
        ->paginate(7);
        return view('levels_subjects.index', compact('levels_subjects','searchText'));
    } 
}

public function create() {
    $levels = Level::where('lev_id', '>', '0')->get();
    $subjects = Subject::where('sub_id', '>', '0')->get();
    $periods = Period::where('per_id', '>', '0')->get();
    return view("levels_subjects.create", compact('levels', 'subjects', 'periods'));
}

public function store(LevelSubjectFormRequest $request) {
    $levelsubject = new LevelSubject;
    $levelsubject -> lev_id = $request->get('lev_id');
    $levelsubject -> sub_id = $request->get('sub_id');
    $levelsubject -> per_id = $request->get('per_id');
    $levelsubject -> save();
    return redirect(route('levels_subjects.index'));
}

public function show($id) {
    return view('levels_subjects.show',['levelsubject'=>LevelSubject::findOrFail($id)]);
}

public function edit($id) {
    $levels = DB::table('levels')->where('lev_id', '>', '0')->get();
    $subjects = DB::table('subjects')->where('sub_id', '>', '0')->get();
    $periods = DB::table('periods')->where('per_id', '>', '0')->get();
    return view("levels_subjects.create", ["levels"=>$levels, "subjects"=>$subjects, "periods"=>$periods]);

}

public function update(LevelSubjectFormRequest $request, $id) {
    $levelsubject = LevelSubject::findOrFail($id);
    $levelsubject -> lev_id = $request->get('lev_id');
    $levelsubject -> sub_id = $request->get('sub_id');
    $levelsubject -> per_id = $request->get('per_id');


    $levelsubject -> update();
    return redirect(route('levels_subjects.index'));
}

public function destroy($id) {

    $levelsubject = LevelSubject::where('lev_sub_id', $id)->delete();
    Flash::success('Eliminado exitosamente.');
    return redirect(route('levels_subjects.index'));
}

}
```

Como dato adicional cuando hago clic en el menú USUARIOS ese me funciona bien! 
pero cuando hago clic en MATERIAS-PARALELOS ahí falla. Se supone que debería salir error en en alguna vista de MATERIAS-PARAELOS o en su Controlador. Por favor ayuda ...soy nuevo con esto de Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Las funciones `index` de ambos controladores te retornan a la vista `user.index` y en el segundo controller no integras el valor de 'users'

Para solucionarlo, revisa si es corecto que te lleve a `user.index` o bien si los valores de `$levels_subjects` pueden remplazarse como `users`

Comment: Gracias @JonathanOrta ha solucionado mi error en mi index.blade.php de mi Usuario sin embargo ahora tengo otro problema me aparece Undefined variable: subjects (View: C:\Nueva carpeta\sisbegn\resources\views\levels_subjects\create.blade.php) de mi levels_subjects. En este archivo blade estoy intentando hacer un Select Dinamico. Lo estoy haciendo cmo tengo en mi contraldor en la imagen de arriba.

Comment: Para las materias estoy haciendo un foreach($subjects as $sub) <option value="{{$sub->sub_id}}">{{$sub->sub_name}}</option> asi mismo para Niveles y Periodos pero no carga los datos en los selects.